# Matrix Multiplication Error: Matrix dimensions must agree

Tags: matlab, matrix, matrix-multiplication

I have this code:

```
function main()
   a = 1.0e+04 * [0.005055052938847,0.010897917816899,0.022355965424711,0.043081981439108,0.077074049394439,0.127074049394439,0.193081981439108,0.272355965424711,0.360897917816899,0.455055052938847,0.552256864601221,0.650978664311931,0.750415022011379,0.850172973479352,0.950071110045004,1.050028912038499,1.150011648830086]
   B = 1.0e+04 * [1.215101736363023,0.697166188613023,0.400000000000000,0.229500515964941,0.131676217070435,0.075549399394941,0.043346565354951,0.024870147785673,0.014269279372341,0.008187017446000,0.004697311820178,0.002695088715947,0.001546310627203,0.000887197716963,0.000509030834515,0.000292057097908,0.000167568136653
   m = timeloop(a,B);
end

function m = timeloop(a,B)
   st = zeros(49,4);
   t = 0:0.001:0.05;
   for i = (1:49)
       st(i+1,1:4) = next_state(st(i,1:4),a,B,1e-4);
   end 
   m = mean(prod(state,2))
end

function next_state = next_state(state,alpha,beta,dt)
   nch = size(state,2);
   p01 = rand(1,nch);
   alphadt = repmat(alpha,1,nch)*dt;
   betadt = repmat(beta,1,nch)*dt;
   next_state1 = (p01<alphadt) .* (state==0);
   next_state0 = (p01<betadt) .* (state==1);
   next_state = state + next_state1 - next_state0;
end
```

but it gives me the following error:

> Matrix dimensions must agree.
>
> Error in `q3>next_state` (line 59)
>       `next_state1 = (p01<alphadt) .* (state==0);`
>
> Error in `q3>timeloop` (line 49)
>       `st(i+1,1:4) = next_state(st(i,1:4),a,B,1e-4);`
>
> Error in `q3` (line 4)
>       `m = timeloop(a,B);`
>
> Error in `run` (line 86)
>       `evalin('caller', [script ';']);`

I've tried changing the multiplication to just `*` with no improvement. What I've looked up [online](https://se.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/322080-how-can-i-fix-this-error-error-using-matrix-dimensions-must-agree) hasn't seemed to be able to help me. I don't understand MATLAB very well so you will have to be very specific in your explanation.

Comment: The actual problem should be explained before posting the attempted solution. This makes it easier to debug your attempted solution and provide alternate/better solutions

Answer (score 1):

If you debugged your code you would quickly realise the issue.

`alpha` in `next_state` is the same as `a` in `main`, meaning it is of size 1x3.

You then create `alphadt` using `repmat(alpha,1,4)`, so it is of size 1x12.

Then you try and do the following

```
(p01<alphadt) .* (state==0)
%   1x12      .*    1x3
```

As the error clearly states, your matrix dimensions don't agree.

Because you haven't given any context for what you're trying to achieve, it's not obvious what the solution should be. Perhaps you want to also use `repmat` on `state`, or loop over single values from `a`.

Comment: Ok, sorry I had some example numbers posted to make my problem look easier, I don't know if the new numbers make a difference but here they are,

Comment: I'm a bit confused what you mean by loop over single values from a.

Comment: What do you want to achieve? If you had a loop which wrapped around your `i` loop, and looked something like `for k = 1:numel(a)` then passed `a(k)` into your function istead of just `a`, then you wouldn't have an error. However, I have no idea if this achieves what you want because you haven't said what that is, and in its current form you wouldn't store all the outputs doing that.